# CSR shared memory, thread, process

Tags: windows, windbg

Windbg extensions !dp, !dt and !address have a parameter that is either a CSR shared memory, thread or process...

What does CSR stand for? Client/Server Runtime Subsystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. For any win32 program, the windows subsystem (csrss.exe) maintains the process information in its structures and same can be dumped using the extensions !dp !dt etc.